# Python binary operators: how to bound inputs so as to bound output

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on project for kids to teach them how to do calculate with operators +, -, *, and /.

In my work, the first and second numbers are random numbers, and they must be less than or equal to some `maxnumber`.  I also want the result of applying the operator to also be bound by the same 'maxnumber'.  I figured out for + and - how to it, but for * and / I don't get my head around.  I know I can build a list and loop until the number is smaller but the project must be really fast and can't get lag from a loop that going until it has a smaller number to continue.

```
if(self.boolOperatorIsPlus):
    self.numberFirst = random.randrange(self.maxNumber)
    self.numberSecond = random.randrange((self.maxNumber - self.numberFirst)
elif(self.boolOperatorIsMin):
    self.numberFirst = random.randrange(self.maxNumber)
    self.numberSecond = random.randrange(self.maxNumber)
elif(self.boolOperatorIsMulty):
    self.numberFirst = random.randrange(self.maxNumber)
    self.numberSecond = random.randrange(self.maxNumber)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly like you did for `+` and `-`. You just have to make sure that you don't divide by zero so you bound `self.numberFirst` between `1` and `self.maxNumber`.

```
.
.
elif(self.boolOperatorIsMulty):
    self.numberFirst = random.randrange(start=1, stop=self.maxNumber)
    self.numberSecond = random.randrange(self.maxNumber / self.numberFirst)
```

For division you should not have any issues, as `a / b` can never be `> max_number` (assuming positive integers and `a < max_number` and `b < max_number`).